# Angular 14 always gives "error" even though it's perfoming the action

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot, angular14

So i'm trying to make a delete button with Angular and Spring boots. The problem is that when I click in "delete" it says "failed to delete component" BUT IT DELETES IT ANYWAY. I have try an "add button" and it does the same thing.

Here's the typescript:

```
`delete(id:number){
  if(id !=undefined){
    this.sExperiencia.delete(id).subscribe(
      data=>{
        this.cargarExperiencia();
        window.location.reload();
      }, err => {
        alert ("failed to delete component")
        window.location.reload();
      }
    )
  }
}`
```

Angular Version: 14.2.4

Comment: This could be an issue with the backend implementation of the DELETE request? i.e. it is reporting a failure but not cancelling/undoing the delete action. What is the endpoint response for the DELETE request in your dev tools? Depending on whether it is a success (2xx/3xx) or an error (4xx/5xx) you would troubleshoot differently

Comment: @nate-kumar I just checked this and the response is success (2xx). I don't know what's happening...